# How to make slanted border stay in correct position across different screen sizes CSS3

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to achieve the slanted left and right borders like the following design

I have been successful in achieving something that looks like it, especially the left and right slanted borders in screen size 1360px. Unfortunately, when the screen size is increased/decreased the left and right borders really mess up the layout. Is there a better way of doing this so that it is responsive and borders stay in correct places?

Here is how i'm coding the layout currently:

```
.f-col1 {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.f-col1::before {
    content: " ";
    width: 104%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(22deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(22deg);
    transform: rotate(22deg);
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.f-col2 {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
.f-col3 {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.f-col3::before {
    content: " ";
    width: 104%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-22deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-22deg);
    transform: rotate(-22deg);
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: -4%;
}
```

I have made a JSFiddle for it: 
https://jsfiddle.net/btmxus6t/

Also, live link where you can see the layout is displaying correctly in 1360px but messes up when screen size is changed: 
http://revolutionarycoder.com/footer/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to keep the same HTML structure:

Forcing the width to stay the same so we'll make sure the element doesn't change in size, including a static top/left/right property to force it into place, rest of the border will just fall off if not neccesary. Do note that this is a custom solution, and will not be *very* responsive if you decide to change stuff.

```
.f-col1::before {
    content: " ";
    width: 260px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -10px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(22deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(22deg);
    transform: rotate(22deg);
}

.f-col3::before {
    content: " ";
    width: 265px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-22deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-22deg);
    transform: rotate(-22deg);
}
```

Comment: Quick, to the point and serves the purpose. I understand if i were to change the content in footer or move things around I would need to modify the widths, but your method provides a responsive solution with fixed with borders, therefore I accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use rotating pseudo elements with heading:

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 white;
  line-height: 4.5em;
  margin: 0 10em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
h2:before, h2:after {
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inherit;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
}
h2:before {
  right: 100%;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
h2:after {
  left: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>
```

Comment: I like the method. Unfortunately the slant you coded is very different to the one in the design but I will play with this and see if I can achieve something similar. +1 : )